# What does "animated madness" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Could you please help me understand what the author is talking about? I have no idea what "animated madness" means. I don't understand it.

> Many of these sequences are short, funny and downright tame compared
>   to the cartoonish nonsense that would come in a few seasons. But they
>   were also startlingly out of place in a show that had never made use
>   of them before. The Simpsons was increasingly relying on cartoonish
>   tricks and (danger free) action sequences to tell its stories, and was
>   making those parts even harder to swallow by playing the over-the-top
>   moments of **animated madness** for suspense instead of comedy.
>
> [Source](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs8/)

Comment: The Simpsons is an "animated cartoon", so you could understand the cited usage as a reference to *madness as displayed through the technique of **cartoon animation***. But it could also be a more "metaphorical" reference to ***animated = energetic, lively*** (similar to ***agitated***, but without the negative "troubled,disconcerted" overtones). Arguably your *exact* context deliberately invokes both senses for stylistic effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Animated*" literally means "full of life or excitement; lively", but is also used to describe a process of making cartoons and the like, whereby inanimate things - for example, drawings, clay models etc - are given the appearance of moving, or being alive.

"*Madness*" can mean crazy behaviour, or perhaps wild, chaotic activity.

"Animated madness" therefore could either mean:

- a cartoon animation which portrays wild, crazy behaviour, or
- a real-life scene of such behaviour that is exceptionally lively.

Your text, which appears to be a film review, seems to be describing a "real life" portrayal (as opposed to an "animation"), and so I would normally assume it was the latter of my two definitions above. However, as the review uses the adjective "*cartoonish*" as an insult (suggesting that the real-life portrayal was as unrealistic as a cartoon), there is a *possibility* that the phrase "animated madness" is a callback to that.